# Filtered backprojection implementatoin

Tags: filters, fourier-transform

I am wondering the detail of the filtered backprojection.

Suppose I have a projection file:

$p(s,\theta)$=`[1 2 3 1 2]`

Then to get its filtered backprojection version using ramp filter, I should

1. apply FFT to it, to get its Fourier version $P(\omega,\theta)$
2. To use |$\omega$| to multiply $P(\omega,\theta)$
3. Backprojection

I am a little confused at second step here.

Using the numeric example above, to apply FFT to `[1 2 3 1 2]`, we will get a complex sequence

```
   9.0000 + 0.0000i 
  -1.0000 - 1.1756i
  -1.0000 + 1.9021i
  -1.0000 - 1.9021i
  -1.0000 + 1.1756i
```

Should I apply |$\omega$| to both real and complex part  of the sequence above, then do inverse FFT? Or should I only take the magnitude of above sequence, apply |$\omega$| to the magnitude, then do inverse FFT?

Either way, it seems I will get a complex sequence as the final results, but shouldn't the filtered projection be a real sequence? Anyone give me some pointers here? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it by creating a convolution kernel, then FFT the kernel, FFT the projection file, then multiply these two, then do IFFT to the product. Then the result of the IFFT is the filtered backprojection.